# renderizado defaultValue en select con react

Tags: reactjs, redux

Estoy intentando renderizar un .map de un array de objetos, y el caso es que al renderizarlo muestra bien el default value del select del segundo objeto pero del primero no. El dato lo cojo de redux.

```
currProfile.map((training, index) => {
return (
    <div key={index}>
     <select
       className="form-select"
       id="floatingSelect"
       aria-label="Floating label select example"
       name="level"
       defaultValue={currProfile[index].level}
       onChange={event => handleTrainingChange(index, event)}>
      <option value="">Selecciona nivel</option>
      <option value="nivelUno"> nivel uno </option>
   </div>
)}
```

Comment: probaste setear el `defaultValue={training.level}`?

Comment: sí, lo probé, ya encontré la solución, cambie el devaultValue por value y me renderiza bien el valor y me permite cambiarlo sin problemas, gracias por contestar!